# Pdf exports from SQL Server 2012 are 3 times bigger than from SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

This is my first post so please bear with me if I don't follow etiquette.

I have built a suite of reports through Visual Studio. Recently, we updated from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012. After this, all of my reports that are exported to PDF appear to have tripled in size & the only way I can get the size down is to reduce the logo images that I use to a 60ppi GIF.

Is there anything else that I can do?